# JBOSS/JSP script bash duration execution

Tags: bash, jsp, jboss, sh

i made a bash script who read a CSV file containing about 1000 lines. 
the script process issue is to add certificates entities to EJBCA plateform. 
the server runs on SUSE with JBOSS.

The .sh script works perfectly from root CLI and now i'm working to create a HIM with JSP pages.

The JSP pages works perfectly by testing with a 20 lines CSV files.

the process:

1. i upload the CSV file from html form
2. a JSP page is saving the SCV file on a specific folder on SUSE
3. after the CSV file is saved, the JSP page reads CSV informations like numbers of lines and then, i display a estimate time duration for my script.
4. a button "execute" with the following code is to launch the script

   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/folder/myscript.sh);
   p.waitFor();
5. the execution of script is OK, my 20x certificates entites are create in my CA sotfware

but, if i upload a CSV file containing 1000 lines or less, the process stops after 10min of script execution for unknow reason.

if i process the execution of script with CLI from server with my 1000 lines CSV files, it's OK !

my questions :
What can be the problem ? 
is there a timeout duration for executing script from JSP page? 
is there any solution for launch remotly the script from server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by myself.

I execute a first bash script from JSP page with 'nohup' argument and this script exécute a second one directly on server. Now my 1000 lines are fully processed !